# Faster way to populate data mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hi I am using Laravel 5 and Laravel Excel http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs.

I am working in a reporting module that will be exported to excel. I have three tables.

`Forms, FormsResponses and Metrics`

```
Forms
->id
->phone_number
->calldatetime

FormsReponses
->id
->Forms_id
->Metrics_id
->Response

Metrics
->id
->description
```

So as you can see I have a Form which has a list of metrics and then the user will select responses for each metrics. Resposes can be Yes,No,N/A. And I have this report. Let's say I have 3 Metrics for now which can be increased if we added new Metrics.

```
Metrics ID|Metrics Description|Phone1|Phone2|Phone3 ...
__________|___________________|______|______|______|___
1         |Sample1            |Yes   |Yes   |Yes 
__________|___________________|______|______|__________
2         |Sample2            |Yes   |No    |No
__________|___________________|______|______|__________
3         |Sample3            |Yes   |No    |No
```

So what I'm doing is I am showing the Responses of each phone number on each metrics. I have a From Date and To Date. This report will be outputed in an excel file which I already have. So this report expands Vertically (Depends on the number of Metrics) and as well Horizontally depending on the number of phone numbers i will get in my Date Range. I can populte it properly. But it's too slow. Processing takes a lot if time and I see that it is cause in my code that searches for the Responses. My code:

```
$query = "SELECT id, phone FROM qcv.forms WHERE calldatetime >= '$from' AND calldatetime <= '$to' ORDER BY id ASC ;";
$phone = DB::connection('mysql')->select($query);

      $metrics = Metric::all();
      $metric_start = 10;
      $start = "D";
      $count = 10;

      foreach ($phone as $key => $value2) // Populate Phone Numbers Horizontally
      {
          $sheet->cell($start.'9', $value2->phone);
          // This will fill the responses for each number
          foreach ($metrics as $key => $value)
          {
              $responses = FormResponses::where('form_id', '=', $value2->id)->where('metrics_id', '=', $value->id)->get();
              $sheet->cell($start.$count, $responses[0]->response);
              // Populate Metrics Vertically
              $sheet->cell('C'.$count, $value->question);
              $sheet->cell('B'.$count, $value->description);
              $sheet->cell('A'.$count, $value->metrics_name);
             $count++;
          }
          $start++;
          $count = 10;
      }
```

And

```
$responses = FormResponses::where('form_id', '=', $value2->id)->where('metrics_id', '=', $value->id)->get();
```

That line takes up the time because for each phone number it has to search the responses for each metrics I have. So imagine if I have 30 Metrics and 150 Phone numbers. It will take time. Is there a better approach to it?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a better approach to use `fromArray` [method](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#array), it would seem it's more efficient instead of creating to track it yourself. I used to same strategy in a export script i created for our company.

**Create the array's you desire**, like:

```
$forms = [
    ['id', 'phone_number', 'calldatetime'], // headers
    // total of 5 dataset items
];

$formsReponsesStartAtRow = $formsStartAtRow + count($forms) + ;
$formsReponses = [
    ['id', 'Forms_id', 'Metrics_id', 'Response'], // headers
    // total of 15 dataset items
];

$metrics = [
    ['id', 'description']
    // total of 100 dataset items
];
```

When your data is ready calculate the start row from each array.

```
// leave between each dataset 2 rows
$rowSpacing = 2;
$startCol = 'A';

// start cell A1
$startAtRow = 1;
$forms = [...];
// add $forms to the sheet
$sheet->fromArray($forms, null, $startCol . $startAtRow);

// calculate start row from previous $startAtRow
// start cell is: 5 + 2 = 7 = A7
$startAtRow = $startAtRow + count($forms) + $rowSpacing;
$formsReponses = [...];
// add $formsReponses to the sheet
$sheet->fromArray($formsReponses, null, $startCol . $startAtRow);

// calculate start row from previous $startAtRow
// start cell is: 7 + 15 + 2 = 24 = A24
$startAtRow = $startAtRow + count($formsReponses) + $rowSpacing;
$metrics = [...];
// add $metrics to the sheet
$sheet->fromArray($metrics, null, $startCol . $startAtRow);
```

If you add a another dataset that one will start on: `24 + 100 + 2 = 126 = A126`

Whenever your dataset grows your excel anticipate on the changes.

Hope this helps you.