# Object Array Searching PHP Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am using Laravel 5 and I want to make an array search. But problem is the query returns an object, so what I did is typecast it, when I typecast it to array still there is an object in in.

So I have this table

```
FormResponses
->id
->form_id
->metrics_id
```

Then my query

```
$responses = FormResponses::where('form_id', '>=', 1)->where('form_id', '<=', 500)->get();
$responses =  (array) $responses;

$neededObjects = array_filter(
          $responses,
          function ( $e) {

              return $e->form_id == 1 && $e->metrics_id == 1;
          }
      );
```

So as you see, `$needObjects` is my variable for the filtered array. I am doing that for searching a record. You can see

```
return $e->form_id == 1 && $e->metrics_id == 1;
```

Which means I want to search all the records in the array where the

`form_id = 1` and  `metrics_id = 1`

That is the output of `$responses` when NOT cast to array

```
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[3423]
      protected 'items' => 
        array (size=3072)
          0 => 
            object(App\Http\Models\FormResponses)[3424]
              protected 'table' => string 'forms_responses' (length=15)
              protected 'connection' => null
              protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
              protected 'perPage' => int 15
              public 'incrementing' => boolean true
              public 'timestamps' => boolean true
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array (size=7)
                  ...
              protected 'original' => 
                array (size=7)
                  ...
              protected 'relations' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'hidden' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'visible' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'appends' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'fillable' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'guarded' => 
                array (size=1)
                  ...
              protected 'dates' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'dateFormat' => null
              protected 'casts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'touches' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'observables' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'with' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'morphClass' => null
              public 'exists' => boolean true
              public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
```

after `$responses =  (array) $responses;`

```
        array (size=1)
      '�*�items' => 
        array (size=3072)
          0 => 
            object(App\Http\Models\FormResponses)[3424]
              protected 'table' => string 'forms_responses' (length=15)
              protected 'connection' => null
              protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
              protected 'perPage' => int 15
              public 'incrementing' => boolean true
              public 'timestamps' => boolean true
              protected 'attributes' => 
                array (size=7)
                  ...
              protected 'original' => 
                array (size=7)
                  ...
              protected 'relations' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'hidden' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'visible' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'appends' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'fillable' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'guarded' => 
                array (size=1)
                  ...
              protected 'dates' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'dateFormat' => null
              protected 'casts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'touches' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'observables' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'with' => 
                array (size=0)
                  ...
              protected 'morphClass' => null
              public 'exists' => boolean true
              public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
```

Comment: Laravel has its own method named as `->toArray()`. So instead of typecasting you can simply use `$responses->toArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel Collections have `toArray()` method:

```
$responsesArray = $responses->toArray()
```

[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this. What will happen to this line return $e->form_id == 1 && $e->metrics_id == 1; Coz it should be array .

Comment: @JoeneFloresca presumably `$e['form_id'] == 1 && $e['metrics_id'] == 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to post process the data? Just query for the records you want:

```
$responses = FormResponses::where('form_id', '=', 1)->where('metrics_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Nope I can't because I have a huge amount of data to search so making a loop and executing that query everytime will take a lot of time. That's my first approach and revise it.

Comment: I still believe SQL is the answer, probably with a groupby clause, but without knowing your actual requirements, then the anser by @Ján Kyselica should work for you

Comment: Originally, this is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934746/faster-way-to-populate-data-mysql-and-php then it is very slow. It's like the approach you told me so I change it. I will try to get all what I need first then store it to array and do the search and I'll see if this will be way faster

Comment: Ok, ill take a look if i get a change. My guess is you can craft a single query to get the data. Your code in that question is slow because its making a ton of queries in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah thats the cause of it. Till now I'm still thinking an alternative method. I have thought of doing that in a single query but seems not possible in my case or either I don't know what the query structure should be.